# According to who?

Tags: riddle, word

1. > Done in Princeton with disgust.
   >   Or, basically, to cover floors.
2. > A blot or smudge,
   >   Or anything up to C.
3. > Eighty percent luck,
   >   Or in sound by sight.
4. > In a public lavatory
   >   Or a house of ill repute.

Together, what are we?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done in Princeton with disgust. Or, basically, to cover floors.

> Mathew - Princeton is renowned for **Math** + **ew** for disgust.
>  Basically is mat, to mean cover floors.  And Mathew is a variant of Matthew.

A blot or smudge, Or anything up to C.

> Mark - the smudge, or an exam mark % up to 100 (C in Roman numerals).

Eighty percent luck, Or in sound by sight.

> Luke - is 80% fluke, or sounds like look.

In a public lavatory Or a house of ill repute.

> John - slang for a toilet, or say, a brothel worker's client.

Together, what are we?

> The Gospels according to Matthew, Mark, Luke and John.

Comment: The answer according to Tom is correct! The only bit that's not what I intended is the 4th line. A, B, or C would be a *grade* not a mark, and there's also D, E, and F.

Comment: PS. I had to try really hard to *not* make part 4 excessively dirty ...

Comment: @Rand - maybe 2 uses Roman numerals?

Comment: That's the one.